# Create a custom react native component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm not an expert on react, and I can't find a way to do this, but how can I create a custom component that I could be used like this:

```
<MyComponent>
   <View></View>
   <View></View>
        ...
</MyComponent>
```

Where, inside  I could place whatever I want. The MyComponent could be:

```
<View>
   <View> 
   </View> <-- Header 
   <View> 
   </View> <-- Content
     Childs, the two Views, would be placed here.
   <View>
   <View>
   </View> <-- Fotter
</View>
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Thanks very much in advance :)

Comment: It seems unclear what you are trying to accomplish, Can you explain what your trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to create the MyComponent and use it by <MyComponent><MyComponent/> and place any childs components I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your MyComponent like this

```
<View>
   <View> 
   </View> <-- Header 
   <View> 
   </View> <-- Content

    {this.props.children}

   <View>
   </View> <-- Footer
</View>
```

Comment: thank you, I tried this, but I guess I did not try hard enough

Comment: You're welcome. I just solved a bug that took my 13 hours of non-stop working.Enjoy your life haha.